# Custom block won't display in admin - Drupal 7

Tags: 7, blocks

I am running into an issue where my block won't show up in the admin section of my site. I've added it to `example_block_info()` where the other existing blocks are declared. I've also added content in `example_block_view()`:

```
/*block_info*/

$blocks['example'] = array(
    'info' => 'Example',
    'status' => TRUE,
    'visibility' => BLOCK_VISIBILITY_LISTED,
    'pages' => 'example/1*',
            'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE
);

/*block_view*/

switch($delta){

...

    case 'example':
        $block['content'] = '
            //content
        ';
        break;

}
```

Am I missing something? All the other blocks show up and work fine. I can modify them as well. This one doesn't work/show up.

Comment: you don't show the rest of the blocks in the code... is there a duplicate name?

Answer (score 1):

Try the next code below, it work for me:

```
/**
 * implements hook_block_info().
 */
function mymodule_block_info() {
  $blocks['hello-message'] = array(
    'info' => t('Message'),
    'status' => TRUE,
    'visibility' => BLOCK_VISIBILITY_LISTED,
    'pages' => 'example/1*',
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  );

  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * implements hook_block_view().
 */
function mymodule_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();

  if ($delta == 'hello-message') {
    $block['subject'] = t('Message');
    $block['content'] = t('Hello World!');
  }

  return $block;
}
```

See https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/block_example%21block_example.module/7